# How to put Django query filter in ON clause instead of WHERE clause?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In SQL, the placement of a condition, whether in the ON clause or the WHERE clause, can affect the results. `filter()` in Django seems to put conditions in the WHERE clause.

Say I have these models:

```
class Nations(models.Model):
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class People(models.Model):
    nation = models.ForeignKey(Nations, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And I want to find the nations with no people in them, I could do:

```
SELECT nations.id, nations.deleted
FROM nations
LEFT JOIN people
   ON people.nation_id = nations.id
WHERE people.id IS NULL;
```

But let's say people can be soft deleted, and I want to find nations with no undeleted people in them. I would do:

```
SELECT nations.id, nations.deleted
FROM nations
LEFT JOIN people
   ON people.nation_id = nations.id
   AND people.deleted IS FALSE
WHERE people.id IS NULL;
```

However, in Django, if I do:

```
Nations.objects.filter(people__id__isnull=True, people__deleted=False)
```

This is equaivalent to the query:

```
SELECT nations.id, nations.deleted
FROM nations
LEFT JOIN people
   ON people.nation_id = nations.id
WHERE people.id IS NULL
   AND people.deleted IS FALSE;
```

Unlike the desired query, this will not include nations that have deleted people only! How can I get Django to move the soft delete check into the ON clause?

Comment: I'm surely overlooking something, but both queries look identical to me, and they do not even seem to make sense. `people.id IS NULL` means there is no matching row in on the right hand side (as you say, nations without people). What sense does it make to further filter the non-existing people on `people.deleted IS FALSE`? Did you actually intend an `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: You are right that the `people.deleted IS FALSE` unnecessary in the last query. It is very necessary in the second to last query, which is the desired output. I kept it included because that is what Django runs and to emphasize the different location of the `people.deleted IS FALSE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little-known feature since Django 2.0 named `FilteredRelation` which allows adding additional filters to a relationship. The result is an additional criterion in the `ON` clause of the join:

```
nations = (Nations.objects
    .annotate(no_deleted=FilteredRelation(
        'people',
        condition=Q(people__deleted=False)))
    .filter(no_deleted=None)
)

print(str(nations.query))
```

The resulting SQL looks pretty much like what you are after:

```
SELECT "app_nations"."id",
       "app_nations"....
FROM "app_nations"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_people" no_deleted ON 
    ("app_nations"."id" = no_deleted."nations_id"
     AND (no_deleted."deleted" = FALSE))
WHERE no_deleted."id" IS NULL
```

Comment: Woo, filtered relation!

Answer (score 0):

Reading you last sentence it seems you want to include nations with no people and nations with only deleted people. To get that, you simply [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#s-exclude) those nations that have undeleted people:

```
qs = Nations.objects.exclude(people__deleted=False)
```

Comment: You're right that this will work for this specific use case, which does help me. However, I'm hoping for a more generic answer about how to add conditions to an ON clause using Django.