# What is the difference between annotations and regular lookups using Django's JSONField?

Tags: django, django-postgresql, django-jsonfield

You can query Django's JSONField, either by direct lookup, or by using annotations. Now I realize if you annotate a field, you can all sorts of complex queries, but for the very basic query, which one is actually the preferred method?

Example: Lets say I have model like so

```
class Document(models.Model):
    data = JSONField()
```

And then I store an object using the following command:

```
>>> Document.objects.create(data={'name': 'Foo', 'age': 24})
```

Now, the query I want is the most basic: Find all documents where `data__name` is `'Foo'`. I can do this 2 ways, one using annotation, and one without, like so:

```
>>> from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL
>>> Document.objects.filter(data__name='Foo')
>>> Document.objects.annotate(name = RawSQL("(data->>'name')::text", [])).filter(name='Foo')
```

So what exactly is the difference? And if I can make basic queries, why do I need to annotate? Provided of course I am not going to make complex queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason whatsoever to use raw SQL for queries where you can use ORM syntax. For someone who is conversant in SQL but less experienced with Django's ORM, `RawSQL` might provide an easier path to a certain result than the ORM, which has its own learning curve.

There might be more complex queries where the ORM [runs into problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058554/django-annotate-count-in-jsonfield-with-postgres/55076146#55076146) or where it [might](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54697320/how-to-put-django-query-filter-in-on-clause-instead-of-where-clause/54698090#54698090) [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135563/django-orm-left-join-on-fields-with-same-values/55136942#55136942) give you the exact SQL query that you need. It is in these cases that RawSQL comes in handy – although the ORM is getting more feature-complete with every iteration, with

- [Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) (since 1.10),
- [Window](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) functions (since 2.0),
- a constantly growing array of wrappers for database functions
- the ability to define custom wrappers for database functions with [Func expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) (since 1.8) etc.

Comment: This does not answer the question, and there are absolutely reasons to use `RawSQL` in many cases.

Comment: I tried to answer in the first sentence, sorry if I wasn't clear: There is *no reason whatsoever to use RawSQL in your example*. As to the necessity of using RawSQL in more complex cases, I did acknowledge this in my second paragraph.

Comment: Fair enough I guess, however I was hoping for some lower level differences between the 2 query methods.

Comment: You can easily inspect the 'lower level' by [asking Django for the SQL of a queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780414/django-1-11-20-get-count-of-rows-per-iso-week-and-year#answer-54781620) or by [displaying the last executed SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362648/print-sql-queries-in-jupyter-notebook-with-django-extensions-plugin/54632855#answer-54632855). In your example, there are only minor syntactical differences between the two queries.

Answer (score 1):

They are interchangable so it's matter of taste. I think `Document.objects.filter(data__name='Foo')` is better because:

- It's easier to read
- In the future, MariaDB or MySql can support JSON fields and your code will be able to run on both PostgreSQL and MariaDB.
- Don't use RawSQL as a general rule. You can create security holes in your app.